# Unable to connect google apps script to mysql through localhost

Tags: mysql, jdbc, google-apps-script, connection, localhost

Getting the error :"Failed to establish a database connection. Check connection string, username and password. " if I run the following script.I am able to connect locally through mysql workbench but unable to do so with googleapp script.Don't know where I am goin wrong .Also,do i need to set triggers if i write the script for a spreadsheet .

```
function test() { 
  var conn = Jdbc.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test", "root",""); 
  var stmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM info;"); 
  var dbList = stmt.executeQuery(); 
   dbList.next(); 
   var row = 0; 
  Logger.log("Start of Log:"); 
   while(dbList.next())
   { 
     Logger.log(dbList.getString(1)); 
     row++; 
   } 
  }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The IP address `127.0.0.1` represents your local computer. It cannot be used by other computers on the network to reach your computer. Remember that Google Apps Script runs on Google's servers and therefore, you need to provide an IP address that they can reach.

Another common mistake many folks make is to provide a 192.168.x.x or some similar internal IP address. So, provide an IP address that is accessible to external computers.

Answer (score 4):

Okay so if you are doing this from your home and want to run google app scripts  your local  MYsql database  on your laptop follow the below steps:-

1)Expose port 3306 on your laptop to the internet.

Login to your router and port forward the 3306 port to your laptop:-
Here is a short youtube video if you own a netgear router. Basically what you are doing here is; when the google script running on the google servers tries to locate your database it hits the router(public IP) on port 3306. Now from there this request gets routed to your specific laptop.Example  port forwarding video:-
[Port Forwarding Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kXwRVg4gadg)

2)Open up the MYSql data  to anybody with a **username** and  **password** from any computer:-
run the following command on your MySQL database:-

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'username'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

3)Use your public IP in the following line :-
So instead of
    var conn = Jdbc.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test", "root",""); 
use the following

```
var conn = Jdbc.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test", "root","");
```

Just in case you face IPV6 and JDBC compatibility issues like most will. Get your public IP from the following address:-
[get my IPV4 address](https://ipv4.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=what%20is%20my%20ip)

So instead of 127.0.0.1 use the results from the above google query